# merge csv files in Python

Tags: python, csv, merge

for example:

input csv1:

```
id,count
1A,9
2A,8
4A,3
6A,5
```

input csv2:

```
id,count
1A,2
2A,2
3A,1
4A,7
```

input csv3:

```
id,count
1A,2
5A,1
6A,1
8A,2
9A,1
```

the 'id's are not equally distributed in all 3 csv files, some are shown in 1 file and some are not.

The output csv file I want is look like this:

output.csv (sum up the count values by id)

```
id,count
1A,13
2A,10
3A,1
4A,10
5A,1
6A,6
8A,2
9A,1
```

**OR**

output.csv (list all count values by id, value 0 for the item does exists in the corresponding csv file but exists in other csv files)

```
id,count1,count2,count3
1A,9,2,2
2A,8,2,0
3A,0,1,0
4A,3,7,0
5A,0,0,1
6A,5,0,1
8A,0,0,2
9A,0,0,1
```

Thanks very much for any helps.

====================== updates ====================

Thanks for @Lilith ' answer, it worked for problem 1. I have modified the code to work extra: the code can process all csv file in a given folder, and the rows in result csv are sorted by 'count' value. Cannot get a solution for solution, may try it later.

```
import os
import csv
from skipdict import SkipDict

data = {}      

def mergeCSV(fileDir,outFile,header1,header2):
    getDataFromAll(fileDir)
    writeCSVDatatToFile(outFile,header1,header2)

def getDataFromAll(fileDir):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(fileDir):
        for aFile in files:
            if aFile.endswith(".csv"):
                aFile = os.path.join(root, aFile)
                worker(aFile)

def worker(aFile):
    with open(aFile, 'rb') as csvfile:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
        for row in list(csv_reader)[1::]:
            if row[0] in data:
                data[row[0]] += int(row[1])
            else:
                data[row[0]] = int(row[1])

def writeCSVDatatToFile(outFile,header1,header2):
    sorted_data = SkipDict(data)
    with open(outFile, 'w') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = [header1, header2]
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        for key, value in sorted_data.items():
            writer.writerow({header1: key, header2: int(value)})

mergeCSV('/home/csv/','/home/csv/output.csv','id','count')
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this problem? If you have, include your code and research in your question to show what hasn't worked for you. If not, you should attempt to solve it yourself first and then post the code and research here. It makes your question easier for others to answer too!

Comment: Where's your code ? What have you tried that didn't work ?

Comment: Sorry for not providing the code becuase i couldn't get the code right. I know this is not a code writing service, i am looking for helps. if there is code provided, i will not deny it; but i am also taking any suggestions and advices or rough thoughs that will help me to solve the problem. In  stackoverflow posts, people give advice or suggestions, like 'try *** library, using dictionary' etc. Thank you if you know something and wanted to help; if you don't want to help or cannot help, that is OK. but you don't have to be mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with csv.reader and csv.writer. https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html

Code for your first example:

```
import csv

csv_files = ["1.csv", "2.csv", "3.csv"]

data = {}

for csv_file_name in csv_files:
    with open(csv_file_name, 'rb') as csvfile:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
        for row in list(csv_reader)[1::]:
            if row[0] in data:
                data[row[0]] += int(row[1])
            else:
                data[row[0]] = int(row[1])



with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['id', 'count']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()

    for key, value in data.items():
        writer.writerow({"id": key, "count": value})
```

Answer (score 1):

Quite easy when using `pandas`. Also for more than 3 files.

```
csvs = ['1.csv', '2.csv', '3.csv']

dataCollection = []

for item in csvs:
    dataCollection.append = pandas.read_csv(item)

mergedData = reduce(lambda left,right: pandas.merge(left,right,on='id'), dataCollection )

mergedData.sum(axis = 0)
```